# Possible to keep bad VRAM "occupied"?

Tags: macos, opengl, gpu

I've got an iMac whose VRAM appears to have gone on the fritz. On boot, things are mostly fine for a while, but eventually, as more and more windows are opened (i.e. textures are created on the GPU), I eventually hit the glitchy VRAM, and I get these bizarre "noisy" grid-like patterns of red and green in the windows.

I had an idea, but I'm mostly a newb when it comes to OpenGL and GPU programming in general, so I figured I'd ask here to see if it was plausible:

What if I wrote a little app, that ran on boot, and would allocate GPU textures (of some reasonable quantum -- I dunno, maybe 256K?) until it consumed all available VRAM (i.e. can't allocate any more textures). Then have it upload a specific pattern of data into each texture. Next it would readback the texture from the GPU and checksum the data against the original pattern. If it checks out, then release it (for the rest of the system to use). If it doesn't checksum, hang onto it (forever).

Flaws I can see: a user space app is not going to be able to definitively run through ALL the VRAM, since the system will have grabbed some, but really, I'm just trying to squeeze some extra life out of a dying machine here, so anything that helps in that regard is welcome. I'm also aware that reading back from VRAM is comparatively slow, but I'm not overly concerned with performance -- this is a practical endeavor, to be sure.

Does this sound plausible, or is there some fundamental truth about GPUs that I'm missing here?

Comment: Won't work. The data you upload to VRAM will not stay there forever, and there is no way to keep it in the same place. The driver is managing the vram, and it can load or unload from it any portion at any time(say when a particular buffer isn't used by rendering, it will be eventually un-loaded from vram, to be uploaded later from its RAM copy when it is used again.

Comment: Bummer. I guess I'll leave the question open and see if anyone has any other hot ideas, but I guess it's time to start looking for a new machine...

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is interesting, although I think there other ways that might be easier to implement if you're looking for a quick fix or work-around. If your VRAM is on the fritz then it's likely that there is a specific location the corruption is taking place. If you're able to determine consistently that it happens at a certain point (VRAM is consuming x amount of memory, etc.) then you can work with it.

It's quite easy to create a RAM disk, and another possibility would be to allocate regular memory for VRAM. I know both of these are very possible, because I've done it. If someone says something "won't work" (no offense Pavel), it shouldn't discourage you from at least trying. If you're interested in the techniques that I mentioned I'd be happy to provide more info, however, this is about your idea and I'd like to know if you can make it work.

Comment: This is an iMac with a discrete (i.e. does not use main memory for  VRAM). Nothing done to main memory will have any effect on this situation.

Comment: So you're saying that if you loaded a custom kext that manipulated the framebuffer by adding additional main memory into it that there would be zero effect on your VRAM? laptop's do that type of thing routinely; It's really not as impossible as you might think, and there would have to be some inlet and outlet for memory to flow back and forth.

Comment: This isn't a laptop. The graphics hardware is not integrated. "Adding additional main memory into a frame buffer" sounds totally foreign to me. If you have a reference for this, I'd love to see it.

Comment: @ipmcc, Yes, I'm quite aware that the iMac is not a laptop, and what I've explained is relevant regardless. The graphics (whether using on-board memory or not) are driven by kernel extensions that can be manipulated; how do you think all the haxintosh users are able to get their hardware working? It's the same principle.

Comment: I'm still waiting for that link to something that actually supports what you're saying...

Comment: @ipmcc, Sure, Here's one such [example](http://pikeralpha.wordpress.com/2013/06/27/appleintelframebufferazul-kext/), and [general info on Framebuffers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framebuffer).

Comment: That example is specific to Intel graphics (i.e. AppleIntelFramebuffer), which are integrated and not discrete. Oh well.

Comment: [Have a look here](http://www.osx86.net/files/category/5-videocards/), it's an archive containing kexts for all types of GPU's (discrete and integrated). As I said before, the principle is the same, however, thinking outside the box is something a skeptic need not bother with — anyway, best of luck :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to write an app that ran on boot even before an OS loaded, that would be in the bootloader - why wouldnt you just then do a self-test of memory at that time ?

Or did you mean an userland app after the OS boots into the login ? An userland app will not be able to do what you mentioned of cycling through every address simply because there is no mapping to userland directly for every page.

If you are sure that RAM is a problem, did you try replacing the RAM ?

Comment: You have misunderstood the question. This is VRAM on the GPU, access to which is mediated by the graphics driver.